# how to get Original logged version of a RTC workitem

Tags: rtc, jazz, ibm-jazz, jazzylistview

how to get Original logged version value of a RTC workitem.

not the current version but the original version against which RTC item is logged.

Suppose current version is 2.0 but the original RTC item is logged against 1.0 . I need the last value of version which is 1.0.

Note: verison is a workItem Attribute.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the information by browsing the history of the work item.
As an example, on the web interface, once you have opened the work item, you have a "history" tab where you should see all the changes made. By searching the keyword "version" on the page, you should be able to spot any change in the value of this attribute

[image: Example history for a work item]

I would also invite to read the discussion [about how to get the history of a work item](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/7046/how-to-get-the-history-of-an-work-item)

Answer (score 0):

There is straight forward solution to manage attribute original value programmatically through deploying participant which would be responsible to store original value to some custom attribute before updating new one (you can check it by comparing workitem new & old state's attribute value), So that custom attribute will always pointing to the original value of Version Number attribute that will ease your effort than finding it from history

Hope it will help you